# How to deduce a state from foreign objects states and use it to as a read-only field?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have a Book that has many Page. A Page can be either *read* or *unread*. I store that value in a *state* field.

I can deduce the book state by looking at its pages:

- all pages unread means the book is *unread*
- at least one page unread means the book is *started*
- all pages read means the book is *read*.

I could store and update the book state each time a page state changes, but this is not my point.

Instead I'd like to find a way to use that book *virtual state* as if it was a kind of read-only field. I'd use it to filter results on the website, on the admin, etc...

What's the pattern of this? And how to properly implement it in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pages are linked to the books via a `ForeignKey` relationship, you can filter books based on their related page states by using [related lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) and narrowing down results by filtering more than once.

For example, *unread* books could be filtered by

```
Book.objects.filter(pages__state='unread').exclude(pages__state='read')
```

which gets all books with unread pages, and then excludes from that set the books with read pages, leaving only *unread* books.

*started* books by

```
Book.objects.filter(pages__state='unread').filter(pages__state='read')
```

which gets all books with unread pages, and then narrows down that set to books with both read and unread pages, leaving only *started* books.

and finally *read* books by

```
Book.objects.filter(pages__state='read').exclude(pages__state='unread')
```

which gets all books with read pages, and then excludes the books in that set with unread pages, leaving only *read* books.

If you additionally wanted Python class methods (to use something like `Book.unread` similar to `Book.objects`) you could put these queries in [`model.Manager`s on the Book model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset).

Comment: Combining `filter` and `exclude` works but I had to add a `distinct`, otherwise the queryset returns an instance of book per page (of the given book) matching the combination.